# Java class without default constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I know if default constructor isn't declared and my class don't have any other constructor Java generates a default constructor for me automatically.
If I declare some constructor, I need declare the default constructor manually.

Why is this case **lac4** contains default values in attributes which **not have been initilized in constructor and I don't have default constructor** ("ataque", "vidaAtual" and "vidaMaxima" contains 0)? I know that Java initializes attributes with default values but for my this occurs only in the default constructor.

```
public class CartaLacaio {

    private int ID;
    private String nome;
    private int ataque;
    private int vidaAtual;
    private int vidaMaxima;
    private int custoMana;

    public CartaLacaio(int ID, String nome, int ataque, int vida, int mana) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.ataque = ataque;
        this.vidaAtual = vida;
        this.vidaMaxima = vida;
        this.custoMana = mana;
    }

    public CartaLacaio(int ID, String nome, int custoMana){
        this.ID = ID;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.custoMana = custoMana;
    }

    public CartaLacaio(CartaLacaio origem){

    }

   //Getters and setters
```

}

My main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        CartaLacaio lac1 = new CartaLacaio(1, "Frodo Bolseiro", 2, 1, 1);
        CartaLacaio lac2 = new CartaLacaio(2, "Aragorn", 5, 7, 6);
        CartaLacaio lac3 = new CartaLacaio(3, "Legolas", 8, 4, 6);
        CartaLacaio lac4 = new CartaLacaio(4, "Teste nome", 3);
    }
```

Comment: `"If I declare some constructor, I need declare the default constructor manually."` -- not true in the general sense. You only need to declare this if your program needs it for some reason.

Comment: "Why is this case lac4 contains default values in attributes which not have been initilized in constructor and I don't have default constructor ("ataque", "vidaAtual" and "vidaMaxima" contains 0)?"     Java initializes instance and class variables to default values (0 for Integer types, 0.0 for floating point, false for Boolean and null for references).

Comment: Your question is badly phrased. But if you claim that instance variables that have not been intialized in the (non-default) constructor do not have default values... you are wrong. But have you checked it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...but for my this occurs only in the default constructor.

No, that happens when the instance is created, before ***any*** constructor is called.

---

Just FWIW, if you had initializers on those fields, e.g.:

```
public class Example {
    private int a = 42;

    // ...
}
```

...the code to set those initializers would be inserted automatically into the beginning of every constructor in the class by the compiler.

---

> I know if default constructor isn't declared and my class don't have any other constructor Java generates a default constructor for me automatically. If I declare some constructor, I need declare the default constructor manually.

You're confusing two separate things.

The *default constructor* is the constructor the compiler will generate for you if you don't provide any constructors.

A *zero-parameters constructor* is a constructor that accepts no parameters.

The default constructor is a zero-parameters constructor. If you provide a zero-parameters constructor explicitly, it's not a default constructor. "Default" means just that: The *default*, if no other is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in your statement

> I know that Java initializes attributes with default values but for my
>   this occurs only in the default constructor.

Java automatically initializes attributes with default values also for overloaded constructor or a non-default constructor